# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_null'

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I ran into this error in drf.
This came when i added it to date and gender field in my model

here is my models.py

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
username = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True, unique=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100, blank=False)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default='',blank=True)
dob = models.DateField(allow_null=True, blank=True)
gender = models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 10,blank=True)

class Meta:
    indexes = [models.Index(fields=["first_name"])]

USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name"]

objects = UserManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

I wanted to give null values to dob and gender while registering user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `null=True` instead of `allow_null=True` in dob field.